# Error while trying to install speedtest script

Tags: command-line, scripts

I'm trying to install Speedtest script on my Ubuntu VPS according to the guide located at https://www.speedtest.net/apps/cli
but received an error - please see below:

```
sudo apt-get install gnupg1 apt-transport-https dirmngr
export INSTALL_KEY=379CE192D401AB61
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys $INSTALL_KEY
echo "deb https://ookla.bintray.com/debian generic main" | sudo tee  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/speedtest.list
sudo apt-get update
# Other non-official binaries will conflict with Speedtest CLI
# Example how to remove using apt-get
# sudo apt-get remove speedtest-cli
sudo apt-get install speedtest
```

I would appreciate it if someone experienced could help me with this issue.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. Earlier I already tried installing the script through speedtest-cli. But the problem is that it works only with nearby servers. When I specify a server located in Europe I receive the following error:

```
#speedtest --server 25761 

Retrieving speedtest.net configuration... 

Testing from UpCloud USA ... 

Retrieving speedtest.net server list... 

ERROR: No matched servers: 25761 - this is a server located in Austria while my VPS is located in the USA so the speedtest script works only for nearby US servers.
```

So I wanted to install the original Speedtest script hoping that I can test other Speedtest servers with success.

P.P.S. I also found this note from someone: "Update Sep 2020: With the recent update of SpeedTest.net API, I can no longer get the full list of all testing nodes. It only returns 100 nodes nearest to your request geolocation. "
Update: this is not true, if you install the official speedtest script then it works as expected, not only with nearby servers but works with ALL servers worldwide.

UPDATE and solution: I finally managed to add the key manually with

```
curl -L https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup\?op\=get\&search\=0x379ce192d401ab61 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then I had to delete all speedtest scripts installed earlier. So I used this command kindly offered by @bac0n:

```
locate speedtest | xargs rm -rf
echo "deb https://ookla.bintray.com/debian generic main" | sudo tee  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/speedtest.list
apt-get update
apt-get install speedtest
/usr/bin/speedtest --help
```

Final words: This is so great that there are professionals such as @bac0n who still exist who can kindly help you to resolve any server problems! I highly recommend him as the best expert to everyone who may look for solutions for the server problems.

Comment: Enable the universe repo and do `sudo apt install speedtest-cli`, nothing else is required.

Comment: I tried it already. But the problem is that it works only with nearby servers. When I specify a server located in Europe I receive the following error:

# speedtest --server 25761

Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...

Testing from UpCloud USA ...

Retrieving speedtest.net server list...

ERROR: No matched servers: 25761  - this is a server located in Austria while my VPS is located in USA so the speedtest script works only for nearby servers. So I wanted to install original Speedtest script hoping that I can test other Speedtest servers with success.

Comment: Are you sure about the server number? I am getting the same error

Comment: speedtest --list|grep Austria

15819) Timewarp IT Consulting GmbH (Vienna, Austria) [49.30 km]
15152) fonira Telekom GmbH (Vienna, Austria) [49.30 km]
12390) A1 Telekom Austria AG (Vienna, Austria) [49.39 km]
 7412) kapper.net (Vienna, Austria) [49.39 km]
12777) ANEXIA Internetdienstleistungs GmbH (Vienna, Austria) [49.39 km]

Comment: speedtest --list - is showing me only US-based servers. But here you can see local speedtest servers https://c.speedtest.net/speedtest-servers-static.php  - so when I run this command #speedtest --server 25761 (Austrian server) I receive this error ERROR: No matched servers: 25761.  Somehow the speedtest script works with nearby servers only.

Comment: @marosg #speedtest --server 15819
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from UpCloud USA...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
ERROR: No matched servers: 15819

Comment: @marosg All Austrian servers you mentioned give me ERROR: No matched servers

Comment: ha, look at man page - Speedtest.net is a web service for testing your broadband connection by downloading a file from a **nearby** speedtest.net server on the web.
Now I see it shows me also only servers up to 270km

Comment: @marosg I also found this note from someone: "Update Sep 2020: With the recent update of SpeedTest.net API, I can no longer get the full list of all testing nodes. It only returns 100 nodes nearest to your request geolocation. "

Comment: Is there any other service similar to speedtest.net I could test my VPS speed from worldwide locations?

Comment: @bac0n yes, same this, a slight difference between python and cli, but still same thing.

Comment: @bac0n In the beginning I used speedtest from the repo, then I followed the official guide and ended with this error. But looks like the script only works for nearby servers only. So nothing will be changed even if I install it from the official source.

Comment: @bac0n  speedtest --version
speedtest-cli 2.1.2
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) [GCC 9.3.0]

Comment: @bac0n  How can I fix this error? #sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys $INSTALL_KEY

Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.NTUocuUC8H/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 379CE192D401AB61

gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure

Comment: @bac0n Still same error: # sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 379CE192D401AB61
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.qmlzXTtQd4/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 379CE192D401AB61
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure

Comment: @bac0n nope, still the same error   #sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net:80 --recv-keys 379CE192D401AB61
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.u6ahTe4430/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net:80 --recv-keys 379CE192D401AB61
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure

Comment: @bac0n I would appreciate it if you could provide the list of commands I need to execute as I'm still a beginner in this field. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Anyone, please?

Comment: @bac0n I finally managed to add the key manually with curl -L https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup\?op\=get\&search\=0x379ce192d401ab61 | sudo apt-key add -

Comment: @bac0n now I have another issue, can't run the original speedtest script because can't remove old speedtest script. # sudo apt-get remove speedtest-cli
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'speedtest-cli' is not installed, so not removed

Comment: @bac0n while I have it here:
# locate speedtest
/speedtest-cli
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/speedtest.list
/usr/bin/speedtest
/usr/local/bin/speedtest
/usr/share/doc/speedtest
/usr/share/doc/speedtest/changelog.gz
/usr/share/man/man5/speedtest.5
/var/cache/apt/archives/speedtest_1.0.0.2-1.5ae238b_amd64.deb
/var/lib/dpkg/info/speedtest.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/speedtest.md5sums

Comment: @bac0n Nope, still the same issue # sudo updatedb
# sudo apt-get remove speedtest-cli
Package 'speedtest-cli' is not installed, so not removed

Comment: `locate speedtest | xargs rm -rf` then start the instruction from `echo "deb https://ookla.bintray.com/debian generic main" | sudo tee  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/speedtest.list`

Comment: @bac0n  Done! What should I do next?
# locate speedtest | xargs rm -rf
# echo "deb https://ookla.bintray.com/debian generic main" | sudo tee  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/speedtest.list
deb https://ookla.bintray.com/debian generic main

Comment: @bac0n  Got it! I have just checked again: # sudo updatedb
# locate speedtest
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/speedtest.list    looks like finally deleted

Comment: @bac0n I implemented all commands you mentioned and installed the script. Now I have this: # speedtest --help
-bash: /usr/local/bin/speedtest: No such file or directory

Comment: @bac0n Thank you so much! You solved my problem! You are the Genius! Now Speedtest works and I can test the speed of my US-based VPS with my location in Europe.

Comment: @bac0n Right now the problem is that when I download a big ZIP file from my server the download speed is about 1 Mbps and varying from 300 kbps to 1 Mbps all the time, while I have a strong Internet connection here in EU (35 Mbps download speed for US-based server). Right now the speedtest shows me the following values (the script is run from my US-based server to my EU location): Download speed 115 Mbps, Upload speed 262 Mbps. So I'm wondering why I have so slow download speed of a zip file from my Us-based server to my EU location (about max 1 Mbps only)?

Comment: I don't have a clue what it can be... maybe your vps supplier can answer it better.